# The js changing backgrounds function isn't working

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays, function

Imma trying to create a simple function that change the background of a specific element when the user clicks it

```
const chrollofunction = document.querySelectorAll("article .krolor");

const randomclickfunctionkro = function() {

    const backgrounds = new Array();
    backgrounds[0] = new Image();
    backgrounds[0].src = 'pics/اليكيورا.jpg';

    backgrounds[1] = new Image();
    backgrounds[1].src = 'pics/pain.jpg';

    backgrounds[2] = new Image();
    backgrounds[2].src = 'pics/قزم2.jpg';

    const randomindex = Math.floor(Math.random() * backgrounds.length);

    const randombg = backgrounds[randomindex];
    
    chrollofunction.style.backgroundColor = randombg;
    console.log('The user clicked and changed the color to ' + randombg);

};

chrollofunction.onclick = randomclickfunctionkro;
```

So i guess that there was a problem with the backgrounds function array , But i can't really understand it and I looked for how it should be written and the correct syntax but can't find any problem really

Comment: [`backgroundColor`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/background-color) doesn’t make sense here. Did you mean [`backgroundImage`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/background-image)? Even then, this doesn’t work with `<img>` elements. Have you read the documentation?

Comment: I can see a couple of issues: 1. you are using the `backgroundColor` property to the set the background image. 2. `chrollofunction` is not an element, but a collection of elements (`NodeList`).

Comment: Yh I am  sorry for my mistakes i just started learning js and it was really awesome so i just tried any thing that came to my mind . imma fix it and try again , many thanks for you two

Comment: Um sorry but I can't really understand the " chrollofunction is not an element " part , I believe that I declared it as a variable that will be the element that i choose using the 'document.qeurySelectorAll' property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the background image of an element like so:

```
 chrollofunction.style.backgroundImage = `url(${randombg.src})`;
```

You may also need to add a few styles to make the image fit the container:

```
chrollofunction.style.backgroundSize = "contain";
chrollofunction.style.backgroundRepeat = "no-repeat";
```